# How can Fiddler know when Server got the request and begin to response?

Tags: http, fiddler

When I use Fiddler capture a HTTPS request,

[image]

you see the Statistics Tab, I have a question about it:
how can Fiddler know when Server got the Fiddler request? and how can it know when Server begin to response.

Comment: It’s probably something like “all bytes sent” and “first byte received”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Fiddler API guide

[ServerGotRequest](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddlercore/api/fiddler.sessiontimers#collapsible-Fiddler_SessionTimers_ServerGotRequest):

> The time at which Fiddler has completed sending the HTTP request to
> the server (FiddlerRequestLastSend). BUG: Should be named
> "FiddlerEndRequest". NOTE: Value here is often misleading due to
> buffering inside WinSock's send() call.

To answer your question on a technicality; Fiddler *doesn't* know when the server got the request. It knows when it *finished sending* the request. This doesn't take into account buffers, scheduling and network latency.

[ServerBeginResponse](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddlercore/api/fiddler.sessiontimers#collapsible-Fiddler_SessionTimers_ServerBeginResponse):

> The time at which Fiddler receives the first byte of the server's
> response (ServerResponseFirstRead)

So again; Fiddler doesn't know when the server responded. It knows when it received the first byte. Not pointed out in the API guide, but obviously there are buffers, network latency and CPU scheduling in between the sending of the response and the time Fiddler measures.